# Vectorized array comparison in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, vectorization

I would like to perform the **do-end do** bit of the following pseudocode within Fortran using a single line statement:

```
integer, parameter :: N = 1000
integer, dimension(1:N) :: ArrayA, ArrayB
logical, dimension(1:N) :: ArrayL
...
...
do i = 1, N
    if( ArrayA(i) <= ArrayB(i) ) then
        ArrayL(i) = .true.
    else
        ArrayL(i) = .false.
    end if
end do
```

Is this possible? If so, how do I do so?

Comment: `ArrayL = ( ArrayA <= ArrayB )`

Comment: @MichaelO. That should be an answer and not a comment, unless the qustion is a duplicate (no time to check now).

Comment: @anuvaramban Note that we don't normally call this vectorization, bit *array notation* or *array operations*. Vectorization in Fortran is usually the usage of SIMD parallel instructions.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5):

```
integer, parameter :: N = 1000
integer, dimension(1:N) :: ArrayA, ArrayB
logical, dimension(1:N) :: ArrayL
...
...
ArrayL = (ArrayA <= ArrayB)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mchinoune answer is perfectly good.
I find the WHERE/ELSEWHERE to be more readable, and if you are doing later operations then the MASK is handy, and one visually can identify that as a MASK.

```
integer, parameter      :: N = 1000
integer, dimension(1:N) :: ArrayA, ArrayB
logical, dimension(1:N) :: The_Mask_Where_A_lt_B = .FALSE.
integer                 :: Some_MinVal
...
...
WHERE(ArrayA <= ArrayB) The_Mask_Where_A_lt_B = .TRUE.

!I know that this is not part of the question...
Some_MinVal = MINVAL(ArrayA, MASK=The_Mask_Where_A_lt_B)
```